# Is there a way not to use !important so much in SCSS (react + material)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am working on a Select component in React using Material UI. The project uses external SCSS sheet imported in the script file for the component.

I couldn't find another way to restyle the CSS of the component, but using the generic material UI classes. However, in the end it seems I had to use !important all the time in order to overwrite the attributes.

The .js looks like this:

```
<Select
    value={this.state.age}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    name="age"
    displayEmpty
    className='select-row-items'
    IconComponent = {ExpandMore}
    MenuProps={{
        anchorOrigin: {
            vertical: "bottom",
            horizontal: "left"
        },
        transformOrigin: {
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "left"
        },
        getContentAnchorEl: null
    }}>
    <MenuItem disableGutters={true} value="">123-456-789123456-01</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem disableGutters={true} value={10}>123-000-457889562-00</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem disableGutters={true} value={20}>122-586-888865987-00</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

I can only style components directly within className 'select-row-items' which I assigned myself. For MenuItems I had to use generic classes and !important next to every value so it can work.

Any thoughts on how can I improve the CSS?

My CSS looks like this:

```
.select-row-items {

  .MuiSelect-select {
    background-color: #D5E4EE; //replace with variables for secondary colors (light blue)
    color: #194581; //replace with variables for secondary colors (dark blue)
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 12px;

    &.MuiSelect-select {
      padding-right: 36px;
    }

    &:focus {
      background-color: #D5E4EE; //replace with variables for secondary colors (light blue)
    }

    &::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);;
    }
  }

  .MuiSelect-icon {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #194581; //replace with variables for secondary colors (dark blue)
    font-weight: lighter;
    right: 4.5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  &.MuiInput-underline:before,
  &.MuiInput-underline:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before,
  &.MuiInput-underline:after {
    display: none;
  }
}

.MuiList-root {
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: #D5E4EE; //replace with variables for secondary colors (light grey)

}
.MuiPopover-paper {
  left: 0!important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.MuiMenuItem-root {
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: #194581 !important; //replace with variables for secondary colors (dark blue)
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 12px !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;

  &:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff !important;
  }
}

.MuiListItem-button:hover, .MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected:hover {
  background-color: #194581 !important; //replace with variables for secondary colors (dark blue)
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
}
```

Comment: One thing you could do is duplicate the classname, so instead of `.MuiPopover-paper` you'd have `.MuiPopover-paper.MuiPopover-paper` to bump up specificity. It's still quite ugly, but IMO better than adding important to all rules.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Actually, I used it for one class already, but I didn't think to apply it everywhere. Yes, it works for most of the classes... There are still some !important's left, but looks much cleaner now.

Comment: [mohamed alaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11838991) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66212114) saying "just use StyleProvider from Material UI https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-r1fsr"

Answer (score 0):

Could you render your SCSS/CSS file after the script imported one? That way it would overwrite without having to use the important tag.

Comment: The CSS is imported in the script already (which probably means it overwrites the script style).